# Popup position not close to the cursor position in FireMonkey

Tags: user-interface, menu, popup, position, firemonkey

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior of the TPopupMenu in Firemonkey (Delphi 10.4).
I've placed a TPopupMenu component on the form and I have assigned a couple of messages to test the functionality.
I have also assigned the Popup1 to all the main components - I have a TTabControl that's covering almost the entire area of the form - and I tested the run.
Well, it happens that when I press the right button of the mouse the pop up menu appears, but it is far away from the mouse cursor.
I also tryed unsuccessfully to set some properties of the component, just to see that these are read-only properties (like PopupPoint).
Is there any assignment which must be done before to "popup" the popup?
What am I doing wrong?
I searched on the Embarcadero documentation without success.

OK. This is the main file of a little program that I made for testing the true behaviour of various components, because it was unclear to me when the radio-buttons and the checkmarks are updated when clicked.
It helped me to understand what kind of events are fired by each component.

```
unit MainTestElementi;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, System.Notification, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.Edit, FMX.Memo.Types, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.Menus;

type
  TMainFOrmTestElementi = class(TForm)
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    RadioButton1: TRadioButton;
    RadioButton2: TRadioButton;
    Switch1: TSwitch;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Pulisci: TButton;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label7: TLabel;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Label8: TLabel;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Edit6: TEdit;
    Label9: TLabel;
    Label10: TLabel;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    MenuItem1: TMenuItem;
    procedure CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CheckBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PulisciClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure RadioButton1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Switch1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Switch1Switch(Sender: TObject);
    procedure RadioButton2Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure RadioButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private

  public


  end;


Const
   Line = '-----------------------------------------------------------';


var
  MainFOrmTestElementi: TMainFOrmTestElementi;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.PulisciClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Clear;
end;


procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Edit2.Text := '';
   If CheckBox1.IsChecked then
   Begin
      Edit1.Text := 'Checked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('ONClick Method: Checkbox1 was CHECKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End
   else
   Begin
      Edit1.Text := 'unchecked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('OnClick Method: Checkbox1 was Unchecked');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End;
end;


procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.CheckBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   If CheckBox1.IsChecked then
   Begin
      Edit2.Text := 'Checked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('OnChange Method: Checkbox1 was CHECKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End
   else
   begin
      Edit2.Text := 'Unhecked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Change Method: Checkbox1 was Unchecked');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   end;
end;


procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
Begin
   If RadioButton1.IsChecked then
   Begin
      Edit3.Text := 'Radio 1 CHECKED';
      Edit4.Text := 'Radio 2 UNChecked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RB1 OnClick Method: RadioButton 1 WAS CHECKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End
   else
   Begin
      Edit3.Text := 'Radio 1 UNchecked';
      Edit4.Text := 'Radio 2 CHECKED';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RB1 OnClick Method: RadioButton 1 WAS UNCHEKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End;
End;

procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.RadioButton1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   If RadioButton1.IsChecked then
   Begin
      Edit3.Text := 'Radio 1 CHECKED';
      Edit4.Text := 'Radio 2 UNChecked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RB1 OnChange Method: RadioButton 1 is NOW CHECKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End
   else
   Begin
      Edit3.Text := 'Radio 1 UNchecked';
      Edit4.Text := 'Radio 2 CHECKED';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RB1 OnChange Method: RadioButton 1 is NOW UNCHEKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End;
end;


procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.RadioButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
Begin
   If RadioButton2.IsChecked then
   Begin
      Edit4.Text := 'Radio 2 Checked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RB2 OnClick Method: RadioButton 2 WAS CHECKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End
   else
   Begin
      Edit4.Text := 'Radio 2 UNChecked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RB2 OnClick Method: RadioButton 2 WAS UNCHEKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End;
End;

procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.RadioButton2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   If RadioButton2.IsChecked then
   Begin
      Edit3.Text := 'Radio 1 UNChecked';
      Edit4.Text := 'Radio 2 CHECKED';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RB2 OnChange Method: RadioButton 2 is NOW CHECKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End
   else
   Begin
      Edit3.Text := 'Radio 1 CHECKED';
      Edit4.Text := 'Radio 2 UNChecked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RB2 OnChange Method: RadioButton 2 is WAS UNCHEKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End;
end;


procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.Switch1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Edit6.Text := '';
   If Switch1.IsChecked then
   Begin
      Edit5.Text := 'SWITCH 1 Checked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('SWITCH OnClick Method: Switch1 is now CHECKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End
   else
   Begin
      Edit5.Text := 'SWITCH 1 Unchecked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('SWITCH OnClick Method: Switch1 is now UNCHEKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End;
end;


procedure TMainFOrmTestElementi.Switch1Switch(Sender: TObject);
begin
   If Switch1.IsChecked then
   Begin
      Edit6.Text := 'SWITCH 1 Checked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('SWITCH OnSWITCH Method: Switch1 is now CHECKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End
   else
   Begin
      Edit6.Text := 'SWITCH 1 Unchecked';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('SWITCH OnSWITCH Method: Switch1 is now UNCHEKED');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
   End;
end;

end.
```

And here is the FRM module:

```
object MainFOrmTestElementi: TMainFOrmTestElementi
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  ActiveControl = MenuItem1
  Caption = 'TEST FUNZIONAMENTO COMPONENTI'
  ClientHeight = 502
  ClientWidth = 836
  Position = ScreenCenter
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object CheckBox1: TCheckBox
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 72.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'CheckBox1'
    OnChange = CheckBox1Change
    OnClick = CheckBox1Click
  end
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'TEST ON CHECKBOX'
    TabOrder = 10
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 168.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'TEST ON RADIOBUTONS'
    TabOrder = 2
  end
  object RadioButton1: TRadioButton
    GroupName = 'gr1'
    IsChecked = True
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 184.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 12
    Text = 'Radio Button 1'
    OnChange = RadioButton1Change
    OnClick = RadioButton1Click
  end
  object RadioButton2: TRadioButton
    GroupName = 'gr1'
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 208.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 11
    Text = 'Radio Button 2'
    OnChange = RadioButton2Change
    OnClick = RadioButton2Click
  end
  object Switch1: TSwitch
    IsChecked = False
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 331.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 13
    OnClick = Switch1Click
    OnSwitch = Switch1Switch
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 312.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 146.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'TEST ON SWITCH BUTTON'
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 19
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 261.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object Label4: TLabel
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'When ON CLICK  is fired it is'
    TabOrder = 9
  end
  object Label5: TLabel
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 72.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 217.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'When ON CHANGE is fired it is'
    TabOrder = 7
  end
  object Edit2: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 18
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 88.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 261.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [Pan, LongTap, DoubleTap]
    DataDetectorTypes = []
    Position.X = 472.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 32.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 337.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 417.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 20
    Viewport.Width = 333.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 413.000000000000000000
  end
  object Label6: TLabel
    Position.X = 472.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 16.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 65.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'Events Log'
    TabOrder = 3
  end
  object Pulisci: TButton
    Position.X = 728.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 456.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 21
    Text = 'Clean Up'
    OnClick = PulisciClick
  end
  object Edit3: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 15
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 176.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 261.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object Label7: TLabel
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 208.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 217.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'When ON CHANGE IS FIRED they are'
    TabOrder = 4
  end
  object Edit4: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 14
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 224.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 261.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object Label8: TLabel
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 160.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 193.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'When ON CLICK is fired they are'
    TabOrder = 5
  end
  object Edit5: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 16
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 304.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 261.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object Edit6: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 17
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 352.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 261.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object Label9: TLabel
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 288.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'When ON CLICK  is fired it is'
    TabOrder = 8
  end
  object Label10: TLabel
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 336.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 217.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'When ON SWITCH  is fired it is'
    TabOrder = 6
  end
  object PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu
    Left = 96
    Top = 400
    object MenuItem1: TMenuItem
      Text = 'CLOSE FORM'
      OnClick = MenuItem1Click
    end
  end
end
```

After this there is the PROJECT file as follows:

```
program ProgettoTestElementi;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  FMX.Styles,
  MainTestElementi in 'MainTestElementi.pas' {MainFOrmTestElementi};

{$R *.res}

begin
  
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainFOrmTestElementi, MainFOrmTestElementi);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Please excuse my lack of expertise in editing and asking questions here, because I have always used STACK for learning (it is such an incredible source), and never for asking.
I hope I have interpreted the request correctly and not too verbose.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. Normally you don't need to do anything special to get the popups to work correctly.

Comment: OK. I'm making a form example to lod here.

Comment: Well, what you have posted is NOT a MINIMAL reproducible example. It is not even an example of the erroneous behavior you asked about, because whenever the popup menu pops up, it does so exactly where the mouse pointer is. I think you could have just included one or two `TEdit` controls or `TMemo` control, together with the popup menu. It is also not clear what the error is in the popup position. I expect the popup menu to pop up where the mouse pointer is, as it does. So, once more, please explain the actual error.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misundrerstanding. 
The fact is that I'm seeing the popup showing up randomly but not at the mouse position. Frankly I don't know what to do.