# A problem with TPopupMenu positioning in Firemonkey Delphi 10.4

Tags: delphi, popup, position, contextmenu, firemonkey

My previous question on this problem was poorly formatted so I decided to delete the previous question and repropose it with a better (and smaller) example.

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior of the TPopupMenu component in **Firemonkey (Delphi 10.4)**.
To simulate the problem, I have created a FORM and I have placed:

1. a TPopupMenu component on the form and I have assigned a couple of items
2. a TLayout on it (the FORM in Firemonkey does not have a property PopupMenu)
3. a TPanel, for the same reason, with the PopupMenu1 as property
4. a Tbutton in the center of the Form
   Well, it happens that only a few times of the Right-Button press the pop up menu appears, and when it does, it is far away from the mouse cursor.
   Is there any assignment which must be done before to "popup" the popup?
   What am I doing wrong? I searched on the Embarcadero documentation without success.
   I have prepared a bit of code.

This is the code of the unit:

```
unit MainUnitTestPopup;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Menus;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Layout1: TLayout;
    Button1: TButton;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    MenuItem1: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem2: TMenuItem;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Application.Terminate;
end;

end.
```

and this is the textcode of the FORM

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Layout1: TLayout
    PopupMenu = PopupMenu1
    Size.Width = 177.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object Button1: TButton
      Position.X = 216.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 168.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 185.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 65.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'CLICK ME!'
      OnClick = Button1Click
    end
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    PopupMenu = PopupMenu1
    Position.X = 176.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 232.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 465.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 257.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 2
  end
  object PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu
    Left = 520
    Top = 56
    object MenuItem1: TMenuItem
      Text = 'MenuItem1'
      object MenuItem2: TMenuItem
        Locked = True
        Text = 'MenuItem2'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and this is the code of the project:

```
program TestPopupProject;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  MainUnitTestPopup in 'MainUnitTestPopup.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

I hope this time I've been able to create a correctly formatted question.
Thank you for your help (and pls excuse my lack of expertise in asking).

Comment: I recall I commented on your previous question, that I could not reproduce the problem. Now that @Philip answered I would like to take a peek at that old question. Please, respond with the 8-digit number of your previous question.

Comment: I don't know what a 8-digit number is. This is the number enclosed in the URL of the previous question that I undeleted (I have deleted that question to create a new one).
The number is 75582286
The URL of the question is this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75582286/popup-position-not-close-to-the-cursor-position-in-firemonkey?noredirect=1#comment133354173_75582286

Comment: Sorry for being so mistakeable, I was't explaining myself correctly. Of course I know what an 8-digit numer is, but I didn't know wehere to find that particular code you needed... ;-)

Comment: Ok, no problem. I looked closely at your code, and noted in the form listing under `object Layout1: TLayout` on the next line you have `PopupMenu = PopupMenu1` which is wrong, probably remains from when you originally attempted to have the menu to respond to clicks on the `TLayout`. I tried to reproduce the error you are talking about by adding that `PopupMenu` reference to my code (I also use Delphi 10.4 Community Edition) but no spurious activation of the menu in unexpected locations. The menu pops up only when clicked on the panel, and always exactly where the tip of the mouse pointer is.

Comment: First a BIG thank ypou

Comment: First a BIG thank you for this investigation.
As I said hereunder, I'd like to upload a short video where I captured the behavior of this strange problem. Is it possible to do it here? Or at least an image.
In the last experiment I did neither the correct list of voices of the Popup showed up correctly.

Comment: Hi again, if you do a mistake when editing your message, you can move your mouse cursor over your message, and the text *delete* in red font will appear at the end. Click it to delete the message.

Comment: Posting videos are probably not possible (.gif files are possible) but image files (.bmp, .jpg) are possible. In the editor is a button with a tiny mountain top on it. When clicked, a small form opens onto which you can drag and drop an image file from a folder of yours. Re. menu popup pos: what is the approximate distance in pixels (horz , vert) from mouse pos to menu popup pos (top-left corner)?

Comment: Possibly half of the form size. I'm tired to fight against this problem, that maybe related to an unnumerable series of possibilities. I created a popup menu class by myself, which works fine in all the circumstances I needed and it is less than 200 lines of code, including the declarations of the popup elements. Thanks again for your kind support.

Answer (score 1):

When I try it (also with Delphi 10.4), the popup menu opens at the cursor position as expected.

However, it only appears when right-clicking on the panel, because, the `TLayout` ignores the mouse click.  To change this, check the `HitTest` box in the object inspector.  Then you can pop up the menu on the `TLayout` also.

In addition, if you want the pop-up menu to work anywhere on the form, you should have the `TLayout` fill the form.  This is best achieved by setting it's `Align` property to `Client` or `Contents`.  Although even then it still won't work when right-clicking on another control, such as the button (unless you also set the control's `PopupMenu` property to the popup menu).

Comment: Is there any possibility to upload a small video that I  recorded to show you the behavior of this whole thing? I checked the HitTest on all the components and made them checked, but nothing has changed.

Comment: I'm using the Community Editio of Delphi 10.4.2 (Update installed). Is there any possibility that this version is buggy? I deactivated the Logitec app, the NVidia app and everything that could interfere with the mouse. Nothing has changed. I'm very worried about this problem, because the software that I'm conceiving will make a great usage of the "right-click" feature, with dynamic menus

Comment: Just to test my own installation, I tried to make a VCL project with a simple empty form and a popup menu with a single voice as EXIT.
It works fine.

Comment: I'm starting to think that there is or may be some other component which is affecting the behavior of the original component. I have installed the TMSFCUI components and the GExperts components. It is quite impossible that with the same IDE (10.4.2) we see two different behaviors. I have uninstalled TMSFCUI components, but the result doesn't change.

Comment: I also have GExperts installed (but not TMSFCUI), so that's unlikely to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tired to fight against this problem, that maybe related to an unnumerable series of possibilities. The fact that my installation of Delphi 10.4.2 works differently by those of yours makes me think that there may be something corrupted or broken in my installation. I will repeat the installation once I've time to do that.
So I created a popup menu class by myself, which works fine in all the circumstances I needed, and it is less than 200 lines of code, including the declarations of the popup elements.
Let me say a BIG THANK YOU to both [Philip J. Rayment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2377758/philip-j-rayment) and [Tom Brunberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2292722/tom-brunberg) for your more than kind support.